# Jaxb unmarshall classes located in parent package

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have several xsd's corresponding to different versions ( identified via different namespace ). However among these xsd's there are various complex types which are common across them. Hence there are a lot of duplicate java classes which are generated using XJC.

To avoid that, I moved the common classes in parent package and made the necessary import changes in ObjectFactory.java, however when I try to unmarshal the XML against it, it fails to map the classes moved to the common package.

```
-com.acme
 --com.acme.common // Placing all common classes here
 --com.acme.A
  ---ObjectFactory.java
  ---PackageInfo.java
  ---A.java // References classes in common packages as fields
 --com.acme.B
  ---ObjectFactory.java
  ---PackageInfo.java
  ---B.java // References classes in common packages as fields
```

When unmarshalling A.java or B.java, I am only seeing the root level primitive fields mapping but the other fields are null or empty.

If I keep all the classes together under single package the mapping works fine.

I am using following command to generate jaxb classes :

```
xjc rixml-2_5.xsd -p com.acme.A -verbose -XautoNameResolution
xjc rixml-2_4.xsd -p com.acme.B -verbose -XautoNameResolution
```

Jaxb context is obtained using below code :

```
private static final Class<?>[] classesToBeBound = new Class<?>[] {
            com.acme.A.ObjectFactory.class,
            com.acme.B.ObjectFactory.class };

    private static JAXBContext context;

    static {
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classesToBeBound);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help to to understand if it is possible via JAXB or any other java library ?

Comment: What is your xjc config/setup? How do you obtain Jax context?

Comment: I have updated the required details in the question